# Rochester theme: changing headline not working

Tags: beamer, color, themes

I have Rochester theme presentation (beamer), and I want to change the color of the headline bar. I've searched all around, and found that

```
\setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=red}
```

should theoretically work. But it doesn't. I found a way to change font in headline with

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
    \nointerlineskip
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=0.3em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
        \vbox{}\vskip-2ex%
        \strut\insertframetitle\strut
        \vskip-0.9ex%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Do I need to define here the background color? If yes, how?

Here is the MWE if anyone is interested:

```
%&latex

\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},hyperref={breaklinks=true}%,mathserif
,10pt]{beamer} 
\definecolor{flatblue}{RGB}{0, 82, 156}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{white}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme[named=flatblue]{structure} 
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=red}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\sffamily, shape=\upshape}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
    \nointerlineskip
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=0.3em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
        \vbox{}\vskip-2ex%
        \strut\insertframetitle\strut
        \vskip-0.9ex%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}




\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{time}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}


\newcommand*\openquote{\makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{``}}}
\newcommand*\closequote{\makebox(25,-22){\scalebox{5}{''}}}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@right
\def\shadequote{\@righttrue\shadequote@i}
\def\shadequote@i{\begin{snugshade}\begin{quote}\openquote}
\def\endshadequote{%
  \if@right\hfill\fi\closequote\end{quote}\end{snugshade}}
\@namedef{shadequote*}{\@rightfalse\shadequote@i}
\@namedef{endshadequote*}{\endshadequote}
\makeatother


\title{Random text is random}
\subtitle{Randomness}
\author{N.N}
\institute[Random institute]{Random institute, Somewhere far far away}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sadr\v zaj}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Uvod}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item bla
\item bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Reference}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Reference}
    \bibliographystyle{alpha}
    \bibliography{mybibMIMM}
\end{frame}

\section*{}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\Large
Hvala na pozornosti\\

\end{center}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Also, can the big block underneath the title on the first page be customized somehow? Like adding a custom background, or even doodling something in tikz?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{parent=<your color>}
```

A complete example with some of your settings:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},hyperref={breaklinks=true}%,mathserif
,10pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\definecolor{flatblue}{RGB}{0, 82, 156}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{white}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme[named=flatblue]{structure} 
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=red,fg=white}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\sffamily, shape=\upshape}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{parent=headline}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sadr\v zaj}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the `footline`, you can redefine the colors `author in head/foot`, `title in head/foot`, and  `date in head/foot` which are used for the left, center and right thirds, respectively, of the `beamercolorbox` forming the `footline`:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},hyperref={breaklinks=true}%,mathserif
,10pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\definecolor{flatblue}{RGB}{0, 82, 156}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{white}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme[named=flatblue]{structure} 
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=red,fg=white}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\sffamily, shape=\upshape}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=red,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=red!70!black,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{bg=red!40,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{parent=headline}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sadr\v zaj}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! This works! I can do the same with footer?

Comment: @dingo_d something similar; please see my updated answer.